# Does CEF3 supports JAWS and accessibility?

Tags: wpf, google-chrome, chromium-embedded, jaws-screen-reader, cefglue

I am trying to use JAWS in my application which uses CEF3 as the embedded browser with .NET Wrapper Xilium which is using CEF3 3.2171.1875.
But JAWS only partially reads the screen and does not do it as it does in a chrome browser.
I am using the following line in OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing
commandLine.AppendSwitch(@"--force-renderer-accessibility");

Can anyone tell me does CEF3 supports JAWS similar to a chrome browser? If yes, please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Cef3 is partially jaws compatible. For my WPF application it was not able to read. I tried windows screen reader called Narrator. Narrator is a free screen reader which comes installed by default in Windows. CEF3 works fine with narrator. Narrator is able to read the screen of the application.